# progress bar animation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing progress bar the problem is bar animation is not working. I want bar track moves left to right simultaneously `%` also moves I try but not working animation is not working properly.
can anyone suggest.

thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ProgressBar() {
    $('.progress-bar').each(function() {
      var percent = $(this).find('.progress-bar--barTrack').attr('data-width');
      $(this).find('.progress-bar--barTrack').css('width', percent + '%');
      $(this).find('.progress-bar--label').append(percent + '%');
      $('.progress-bar--barTrack').animate({
        width: $(this).percent,
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
  ProgressBar();
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-s1 .progress--barTitle {
  padding: 1% 1% 3% 0;
  width: 15%;
}

.progress-bar-s1 .progress-bar--inner {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.progress-bar-s1 .progress-bar--barTrack {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #F7CA18;
}

.progress-bar-s1 span.progress-bar--label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-s1">
  <div class="progress--barTitle">Integrity</div>
  <div class="progress-bar--inner">
    <span class="progress-bar--barTrack" data-width="60"></span>
  </div>
  <span class="progress-bar--label"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the width of `barTrack` using `.css()` method and use correct variable i.e. `percent` instead of `$(this).percent` to set width in the animate method.

As per comment *i want to move 60% also simultanously*

You need to animate *.progress-bar--label* also and also modify its CSS rules.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ProgressBar() {
    $('.progress-bar').each(function() {
      var percent = $(this).find('.progress-bar--barTrack').attr('data-width');
      
      $(this).find('.progress-bar--label').text(percent + '%');      
      $(this).find('.progress-bar--barTrack, .progress-bar--label').animate({
        width: percent + '%'       
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
  ProgressBar();
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-s1 .progress--barTitle {
  padding: 1% 1% 3% 0;
  width: 15%;
}

.progress-bar-s1 .progress-bar--inner {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) inset;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.progress-bar-s1 .progress-bar--barTrack {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #F7CA18;  
}

.progress-bar-s1 span.progress-bar--label {
  position: relative;
  text-align:right;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-s1">
  <div class="progress--barTitle">Integrity</div>
  <span class="progress-bar--label"></span>
  <div class="progress-bar--inner">
    <span class="progress-bar--barTrack" data-width="60"></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: i want to move `60%` also simultanously